# Row-normalize matrix

Tags: matlab

Is there any efficient (speed of computation + amount of keystrokes) way to perform row-normalization in MATLAB, using the built in functions?

This is what I've came up with so far

```
A = rand(m, n); % m rows, n cols
v = pdist2(zeros(1, size(A, 2)), A);
normA = diag(1./v) * A;
```

Comment: Normalization can mean many things.  Do you want the sum of the row elements add up to one? Or do you want the maximum element in the row to be limited to +/-1?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want row sums to be 1:

```
bsxfun(@times, A, 1./(sum(A, 2)))
```

**Edit**

If you're looking for the l2 norm as @Oli suggests below, then

```
bsxfun(@times, A, 1./sqrt(sum(A.^2, 2)))
```

In that case, you can semi-gracefully handle zero row sums by doing

```
bsxfun(@times, A, 1./(max(sum(A, 2), eps)))
```

Comment: 안녕하새요. According to his code, I think he needs the L2-normaliztion... `1./sqrt(sum(A.^2, 2))`. Because `pdist2` will compute the L2 distance to a zero vector, which is the L-2 norm.

Comment: Thanks :)  <pedantic>Technically that's the l2 (little L) norm.</pedantic>